# Retrofit2 and Gson not have response in logcat

Tags: android, retrofit2

I try to get json from Retrofit2 (Retrofit 2.1.0) and Gson. But response body is not have. No in on onFailure. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

Retrofit

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logger)
                    .build();


retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RETROFIT_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```